# check if key exists in object with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I need help with lodash cause i dont understand functional programming and lodash is very helpfull with object/arrays operations.

I need to search objects inside object and return true if key exists. I've setup a jsfiddle. Apreciate your help.

```
    var dependsOn={
      "Cadastro": {
        "RHID": "RHID"
      },
      "Agregados":{
        "CD_DOC":"CD_DOC"
      }
      "Documentos":{
        "RHID":"CD_DOC"
      }
    }
    var field='RHID'

alert(_.contains(_.keys(dependsOn), field))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/88gwp87k/

Answer (score 53):

Try this. it's simple

```
_.has(dependsOn, field)
```

it returns true if the `RHID` key exist in dependsOn. in above case it returns false

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
var dependsOn={
  "Cadastro": {
    "RHID": "RHID"
  },
  "Agregados":{
    "CD_DOC":"CD_DOC"
  },
  "Documentos":{
    "RHID":"CD_DOC"
  }
}
var field='RHID'

alert(_.some(dependsOn, function(o) { return _.has(o, field); }));
```

Updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/88gwp87k/1/

Comment: something is wrong. Narendra CM can you help me with this https://jsfiddle.net/88gwp87k/

Comment: Whats the problem?? LeonelMatiasDomingos

Comment: always return false  and seems that must return true https://jsfiddle.net/88gwp87k/2/

Comment: Did you check my earlier fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/88gwp87k/1/. This returns true

Comment: i've solved  other way... can you please help me with returning the object with db=='NOME' in https://jsfiddle.net/4w2z418c/1/

Comment: you can use `_.where(test, {db: "NOME"})` to get all the object which matches the criteria. In this case it is `db = NOME`. Here is hte updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4w2z418c/3/

Comment: as i needed the index also i made  var v = _.result(_.findWhere(window[key].dbColumns, {'db': value[myObj.dbColumns[i]["db"]]}), 'db');
                            var k = _.findIndex(window[key].dbColumns, {'db': v}); thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

```
_.chain(dependsOn).findKey(field).isString().value();
```