# Find key in nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Why does this always return false?

```js
var dependsOn = {
  "Cadastro": {
    "RHID": "RHID"
  },
  "Agregados": {
    "CD_DOC": "CD_DOC"
  },
  "Documentos": {
    "RHID": "CD_DOC"
  }
}
var field = 'RHID'

_.mapKeys(dependsOn, function(value, key) {
  if (_.some(dependsOn[key], function(o) {
      return _.has(o, field);
    })) {
    console.log(key);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: In your fiddle _.keys(dependsOn) is returning 0: "Cadastro" 1: "Agregados" 2: "Documentos" so it should be returning false.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35655548/1988157

Answer (score 1):

```
_.findKey(dependsOn, field); //
```

Comment: thanks soved with  _.mapKeys(myObj.dependsOn, function(value, key) {
                        if ( _.has(myObj.dependsOn[key], myObj.dbColumns[i]["db"])) {
                            var val=

                            myObj.dbColumns[i]["nxt_value"] = window[key].dbColumns[i]["prv_value"];
                            where_str += ' AND ' + myObj.dbColumns[i]["db"] + myObj.conditionClause(window[key].dbColumns[i]["prv_value"], "=");
                            debugger;

                        }
                    });

Answer (score 0):

To get the object (key,value)

```js
let dataAsObj = _.find(dependsOn, field); //  it returns the key of the first element
// { RHID: 'RHID' }
if (dataAsObj !== undefined) {
    console.log(dataAsObj[field]); // RHID
}
```